# android smtp with attachment of db file

Tags: android, email, android-studio, smtp

i am trying to create a android smtp app, in which i want to access the internal storage (Where a .db or .db.crypt file is stored) and from there i want to get that file and sent it via email.
below is my code,where everything is working fine. i am able to get that file and send it. but suppose my original file name is "file1.db" but after sending it through smtp it receives as "file1" which is just a file. 
any one having idea? plz tell me how can i send that db file???

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

//Class is extending AsyncTask because this class is going to perform a networking operation
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
//Declaring Variables
private Context context;
private Session session;

//Information to send email
private String email;
private String subject;
private String message;

//Progressdialog to show while sending email
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

//Class Constructor
public SendMail(Context context, String email, String subject, String message){
    //Initializing variables
    this.context = context;
    this.email = email;
    this.subject = subject;
    this.message = message;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    //Showing progress dialog while sending email
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(context,"Sending message","Please wait...",false,false);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    //Dismissing the progress dialog
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    //Showing a success message
    Toast.makeText(context,"Message Sent",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    //Creating properties
    Properties props = new Properties();

    //Configuring properties for gmail
    //If you are not using gmail you may need to change the values
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

    //Creating a new session
    session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                //Authenticating the password
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(Config.EMAIL, Config.PASSWORD);
                }
            });

    try {
        //Creating MimeMessage object
        MimeMessage mm = new MimeMessage(session);

        //Setting sender address
        mm.setFrom(new InternetAddress(Config.EMAIL));
        //Adding receiver
        mm.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
        //Adding subject
        mm.setSubject(subject);
        //Adding message
        mm.setText(message);

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();


        MimeBodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()+File.separator+"PasswordSafe.db"));
       messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setDisposition(MimeBodyPart.ATTACHMENT);
        messageBodyPart.setFileName("file1");

        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        mm.setContent(multipart);


        //Sending email
        Transport.send(mm);

    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: replace `messageBodyPart.setFileName("file1");` with `messageBodyPart.setFileName("file1.db");` might help you

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick for you..

```
String fileName = name + " yourFile"+".db";
```